# Calling function itselft within exception

Tags: recursion, exception

Hı, 
I try to create a code that when catch an exception call itself one more time but with different argument. Recursion sample is below. 
It is working fine it work for first way if it catch exception call with second way; if it has exception for second way return false, but I want to ask wheter it is a good coding or junk?

```
public void Main(){
 console.log(testing(true));
}

private boolean testing(boolean isFirstWay)
{
 try{
  if(isFirstWay){
   // set something, call some functions for first way
   return true;
  } else{
   // set something, call some functions for second       way
  return true;
  }
 } catch(Exception e)
  {
    if(isFirstWay){
      return testing(false);
     } else {
      return false;
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: Q:  it is a good coding or junk?  A: No way, shape or form would this be acceptable in production code...  Exceptions are intended to "percolate up" - NEVER "recurse down".

Comment: how about solving this issue; if first way has exception then try second way?

Comment: For this issue: 1) eliminate the try/catch block, 2) change signature to "testing(..) throws Exception", 3) put the try/catch block *outside* of "testing()" - in the *caller*.